# Copy e paste multiple rectangular nodes with the right order

Tags: anylogic

In this example I select two rectangular nodes in order to copy and paste it.When i do it, the order of the nodes is not correct (see figure).How do i put them sequentially and automatically(node1,node2,node3,mode4)? thanks
[image]

Comment: the question is why do you need them in order.. otherwise you have to copy one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a sequential list of any object, you put them into a `LinkedList`.

In your case, have a `LinkedList<Node>` or use an AnyLogic "Collection" element, set it to LinkedList and the object type to Node.

Then, check how they work, it is standard Java stuff (independent of AnyLogic). QUite useful data type :)